# Error sending email using XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to send an email using XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript, but I'm facing an issue. Here's what I've tried so far:

I have the following code snippet:

,
.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Email Sending Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Email Sending Example</h1>

    <script>
        function sendEmail() {
            var email = {
                to: 'recipient@example.com', // Replace with the recipient's email address
                from: 'YOUR_FROM_EMAIL@example.com', // Replace with your desired sender's email address
                subject: 'Example Email',
                message: 'Hello, This is an example email!'
            };

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'https://api.intercom.io/email/send', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer dG9rOjhhZa='); // Replace with your Intercom token

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        alert('Email sent successfully!');
                    } else {
                        alert('Error sending email. Please try again.');
                    }
                }
            };

            xhr.send(JSON.stringify(email));
        }
    </script>

    <button onclick="sendEmail()">Send Email</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue I'm facing is that when I click the "Send Email" button, I'm receiving an error message saying "Error sending message. Please try again." I have already checked the Intercom token, and it appears to be correct.

Am I missing something in the code or making a mistake with the XMLHttpRequest setup? I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance for your help!

my best and it should be able to send email

Comment: Check the network request in your developer tools, that should show you what the response was, including the status code and any error message provided.

Comment: Are those your real credentials in the Authorization request-header? It looks like a username-password pair